# Buildspec for Spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aws-codebuild, buildspec

So i stuck on one thing I have an application which was written on Spring boot and located on Fargate behind Application Load Balancer. I should make a load performance testing on that app and create buildspec file, i made it but i completly new in building pipelines for that service, so don't know how to write buildspec file. Could someone please help me and give the right direction how to write the buildspec for that service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example of **buildspec.yml :**
[image]